# Let $(X , \cal{A}, m)$ be a measure space. Let $f:X \to [0,1]$ be measurable. If $m(X) < \infty$, find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f^n \, d m$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X , \cal{A}, m)$ be a measure space. Let $f:X \to [0,1]$ be a measurable function. If $m(X) < \infty$, determine $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f^n \, d m$.

So far I have:

If $f(x) < 1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}{f^n(x)} = 0$. If $f(x) = 1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}{f^n(x)} =1$. So, for each $x \in X$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{f^n(x)} = \chi_{_{[f = 1]}}(x).
$$

However, I am stuck because I cannot use the Lebesgue Monotone Convergence Theorem, since the sequence is decreasing. Also, I do not know where I will use the hypothesis that $X$ is a finite measure space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try using the dominated convergence theorem. Since $f$ maps to $[0,1]$, it is clear that $|f^n| \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Because the measure space is finite, the function $x \mapsto 1$ is integrable. Using this as the dominating function, you can pass the limit inside the integral.

Comment: I see. How do you prove that if $f$ is a bounded measurable function and $m(X) < \infty$, then $f$ is integrable?

Comment: If $|f| \leq L$ and $f$ is measurable then $\int_X |f|\,\mathrm{d}m \leq \int_X L\,\mathrm{d}m = L m(X) < \infty$.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!